# AdMob banner add between tableview cell

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, admob

Hello I want to add Admob banner add between the uitableview currently i am able to do this , but when i append admob add using xib file it remove the record from that index and show the add , i know want to remove index record.

this is how i am appending the Admob add

```
 if noAds == false {
        if indexPath.row % 5 == 0 {
            let reusableAdCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "BannnerCellAds",
                                                               for: indexPath)


            reusableAdCell.contentView.addSubview(adBannerView)
            // Center GADBannerView in the table cell's content view.


            adBannerView.center = reusableAdCell.contentView.center
            return reusableAdCell

        }
        }
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! HomeCollectionViewCell
        let model = dataSections[indexPath.row]
        cell.titlename.text = model.name
return cell
```

Comment: You may want to display an ad as a header or a footer view.

Comment: no i want to display between the cells